# WARNING: Environment does not support cv2.imshow() or PIL Image.show() image displays

Tags: opencv

The following is the error i meet.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1338: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvWaitKey'
```

```
WARNING: Environment does not support cv2.imshow() or PIL Image.show() image displays
OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the
 library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

the environment is python3.8.5,opencv-python==4.7.0,opencv-contrib-python==4.7.0
I use pycharm to operate yolov5's camera detection,it tells me that "WARNING: Environment does not support cv2.imshow() or PIL Image.show() image displays
OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the
library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'"

I have tried reinstalling opencv-python,opencv-contrib-python.However,it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues, but they have been resolved this way:

update pip:

```
pip install -U pip
```

use pip to uninstall opencv:

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Then clear the cache as pip will hold the uninstalled version and just build with that....(took me a while to figure that out)

```
pip cache purge
```

Next install the recommended dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config
```

Finally, install opencv-contrib-python. Takes a while but it worked for me. I hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, using pip install of course